# prove that $g_\theta(t)$ is increasing on $[1,\infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, monotone-functions

Here's an aggravating problem.  Fix some constant $\theta\in(0,1)$.  I have a function
$$g_\theta(t)=t^\theta\left[(t+1)^{1-\theta}-\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1-\theta}\right]$$
which, when plotted in wolfram for various values of $\theta$, is clearly increasing on $[1,\infty)$.  But, I need to prove this rigorously.

The obvious thing to do is to try to show that $g'_\theta(t)>0$ on $[1,\infty)$.  Unfortunately, we have this mess for the derivative:

$$g'_\theta(t)
=(\theta t^{\theta-1}+t^\theta)(t+1)^{-\theta}
-(\theta t^{\theta-1}/2+t^\theta)\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-\theta}$$

Maybe there's some special function I can use to make this easier.  Or some convexity trick I'm not seeing.  Idk.  What do you guys think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the mean value theorem to the function $\phi(t,x)=(t+x)^{1-\theta}$ one can show that: $\phi(t,1)-\phi(t,\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}(1-\theta)(t+\alpha)^{-\theta}$ for some alpha with   $ \frac{1}{2}<\alpha<1$. It follows that: $g_{\theta}(t)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\theta)(\frac{t}{t+\alpha})^{\theta}$ which is an increasing function.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful.  However please note that in your argument $\alpha$ depends on $t$.  So, it doesn't follow that $g_\theta$ is increasing.  On the other hand, I can probably use this argument to bound the function below by an increasing function, which should be sufficient for my needs.

Comment: Yes it' s true, my precedent argument permits only to bound the function between  two increasing functions and this doesn't imply the function itself is increasing.  I think that the quickest way to solve the issue is to  study the sign of the derivative and observing that the function f(x,t)=$\frac{x\theta +t}{t(x+t)^{\theta}}$ is increasing with respect to the variable x if $\theta<1$ and decreasing if $\theta>1$ and$ x>0. $.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer anyway, since all I really wanted to do was find a positive lower bound.  And your solution is good enough for that : )